NameError: name 'xxx' is not defined nor importable as module ** PDB_DEBUGGER
When I'm trying to use pdb debugger for robot framework script Im trying to print the variables however it is impossible for me. I constantly get
NameError: name 'l' is not defined nor importable as module **
When running locals() or dir() variables are displayed correctly, already tried to iterate over these lists, same effect. How can i view the values of these variables listed in locals() ? (I always get NameError: name 'l' is not defined nor importable as module **)
Tried to print variables using pdb_debugger
